# Is it possible to get Excel to search "backwards," i.e. to the left and up?

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, find-and-replace

When you do a simple search in Excel, it seems to scan left to right proceeding down row by row.  Is it possible to reverse this so that Excel instead searches right to left proceeded up row by row?

Comment: Are you just using Ctrl+F to search? If you are then it isn't possible.  However, if you use VBA, you can use ".find" and you can change the direction to xlPrevious which will search backwards through a defined range

Comment: Thanks, @DavePenn.  Yes, I'm using Ctrl+F.  I don't use VBA.

Comment: This link may help you.  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/193296-any-way-search-backwards-within-workbook.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Find and Replace window, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> to search backwards.

After you've hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> the first time, you can close the Find and Replace window and hit <kbd>F4</kbd> to continue through to the next match up/left.

Conversely, you can simply hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the Find and Replace window to find the next match down/right and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to repeat the action in reverse, thus moving up/left.

Comment: Thanks so much!  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially rotate the table 180° onto a new sheet using offset () and do the search on the second sheet. There's a good step by step for rotation on the following [link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4602-excel-rotate-table-90-degree-180-degree.html).

Comment: Please see our help center on the guidelines of a link-only answer.

Comment: The answer initially did not have a link since rotating the table 180° is the solution suggested. Since not everyone knows how to rotate, I included the link for reference.  my point of view, the link was not the answer. Then again, I'm new to the community.

Comment: @FernandoEblagon You're right, this is not a link-only answer. Ramhound was a bit too eager, I think :P